# Getting error (invalid_grant) when accessing docusign

Tags: docusignapi

After proceeding successfully with the go live steps, we are following the post-go live steps and getting this full stack error when trying to access a document in docusign.

```
HTTP response body: b'{"error":"invalid_grant"}2019-09-23 19:49:04,021 wct.controllers.docusign.docusign authenticate ERROR *******GIVE CONSENT URL:https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&client_id=[[redacted]]&scope=signature%20impersonation&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftestfirstuplending.com%2Fdocutest%2Fdocusign_callback.html
2019-09-23 19:49:04,021 wct.controllers.docusign.docusign authenticate ERROR https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&client_id=[[redacted]]&scope=signature%20impersonation&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftestfirstuplending.com%2Fdocutest%2Fdocusign_callback.html
2019-09-23 19:49:06,273 django.request handle_uncaught_exception ERROR Internal Server Error: /wct/docusign/createSignDocument/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mack/dev/wct/wctenv/wctenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/mack/dev/wct/wctenv/wctenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/mack/dev/wct/wctenv/wctenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
return func(*args, **kwds)
File "/Users/mack/dev/wct/wctenv/wctenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Invalid Grant can refer to a few possible error states. Here's a few things to check:

- Is your API Client pointing to the Production environment? That consent URI is to `account-d`, for Demo
- Have you granted Consent in Production? Demo and Prod require separate instances of consent
- Are you using a valid Production UserID in your JWT Assertion?
- Have you generated a new RSA Keypair? Demo and Prod use separate RSA keys.

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

```
ERROR https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=cod...
```

Note the url has -d which is not production. Production would be without it like this:

```
https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=cod...
```